# Using an Example from Deitel's Java Book Not Working

Tags: java, swing

```
// Fig. 14.6: LabelFrame.java 
// Demonstrating the JLabel class. 
import java.awt.FlowLayout; // specifies how components are arranged 
import javax.swing.JFrame; // provides basic window features 
import javax.swing.JLabel; // displays text and images 
import javax.swing.SwingConstants; // common constants used with Swing
import javax.swing.Icon; // interface used to manipulate images 
import javax.swing.ImageIcon; // loads images 

public class LabelFrame extends JFrame 
{ 
private JLabel label1; // JLabel with just text 

private JLabel label2; // JLabel constructed with text and icon 

private JLabel label3; // JLabel with added text and icon 

// LabelFrame constructor adds JLabels to JFrame 
public LabelFrame(){ 

{super( "Testing JLabel" ); 

setLayout( new FlowLayout() ); 

// JLabel constructor with a string argument 

label1 = new JLabel( "Label with text" ); 

label1.setToolTipText( "This is label1" ); 

add( label1 ); 

//JLabel constructor with string, Icon and alignment arguments 

Icon bug = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource( "bug1.png" ) ); 

label2 = new JLabel( "Label with text and icon", bug, 

SwingConstants.LEFT ); 

label2.setToolTipText( "This is label2" ); 

add( label2 ); 

label3 = new JLabel(); // JLabel constructor no arguments 

label3.setText( "Label with icon and text at bottom" ); 

label3.setIcon( bug ); // add icon to JLabel 

label3.setHorizontalTextPosition( SwingConstants.CENTER ); 

label3.setVerticalTextPosition( SwingConstants.BOTTOM ); 

label3.setToolTipText( "This is label3" ); 

add( label3 ); 
} 
}
```

That was class one.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame; 

public class LabelTest 
{ 
public static void main( String[] args ) 
{ 
LabelFrame labelFrame = new LabelFrame(); // create LabelFrame 
labelFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE ); 
labelFrame.setSize( 260, 180 ); // set frame size 
labelFrame.setVisible( true ); // display frame 
} // end main 
}
```

This is class two.

I noticed that with the one untyped (LabelFrame) class did not have a type, but I copied from Deitel's Java book. I assumed we was correct, but so far this is not running because of that little piece of code. I am wondering if it could be an issue with the Java version, since mine is the latest, and the book is from 2012. If you could enlighten me on why this code won't run in Eclipse, that would be greatly appreciated. In addition, the add did not work. Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell what error are you getting?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by 'won't run'?  Also, use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow!

Comment: For a book from 2012 it's quite recent to be violating swing [threading rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). Anyway, telling us the error/stacktrace etc would be useful.

Comment: Does all of your code lack indentations? Doesn't that make it hard to read?

Comment: Sorry for being such a dork. I just noticed the bracket. It still won't run after I take the bracket out at super(""); . But it still won't compile:                                              Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at LabelFrame.<init>(LabelFrame.java:35)
 at LabelTest.main(LabelTest.java:7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK.. it seems the problem is that the code would not even *compile* cleanly.  This was largely due to the lack of logical indentation leading to incorrectly placed brackets.

This code compile, but fails (here) at run-time due to the missing image.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout; // specifies how components are arranged
import javax.swing.JFrame; // provides basic window features
import javax.swing.JLabel; // displays text and images
import javax.swing.SwingConstants; // common constants used with Swing
import javax.swing.Icon; // interface used to manipulate images
import javax.swing.ImageIcon; // loads images

public class LabelFrame extends JFrame
{
    private JLabel label1; // JLabel with just text
    private JLabel label2; // JLabel constructed with text and icon
    private JLabel label3; // JLabel with added text and icon

    // LabelFrame constructor adds JLabels to JFrame
    public LabelFrame() {
        super( "Testing JLabel" );
        setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
        // JLabel constructor with a string argument
        label1 = new JLabel( "Label with text" );
        label1.setToolTipText( "This is label1" );
        add( label1 );

        //JLabel constructor with string, Icon and alignment arguments
        Icon bug = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource( "bug1.png" ) );

        label2 = new JLabel( "Label with text and icon", bug,
        SwingConstants.LEFT );
        label2.setToolTipText( "This is label2" );
        add( label2 );
        label3 = new JLabel(); // JLabel constructor no arguments
        label3.setText( "Label with icon and text at bottom" );
        label3.setIcon( bug ); // add icon to JLabel
        label3.setHorizontalTextPosition( SwingConstants.CENTER );
        label3.setVerticalTextPosition( SwingConstants.BOTTOM );
        label3.setToolTipText( "This is label3" );
        add( label3 );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        LabelFrame labelFrame = new LabelFrame(); // create LabelFrame
        labelFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        labelFrame.setSize( 260, 180 ); // set frame size
        labelFrame.setVisible( true ); // display frame
    } // end main
}
```

Comment: Ok. So that bug is not an internal "bug" image, but external? XD Ok. That explains that.

Comment: It did not fully solve the problem. It still has the error message I posted in the comment section above you answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason add is showing error is because you didn't "extend JFrame in the LabelFrame class,
It should be coded like this:

```
public class LabelFrame extends JFrame{
}
```

that should solve that problem,  On the rest of your question,  I'm having the same problem because the image is not there,  It's null,  If anyone can tell me how to get the image and use it,  that would be greatly appreciated,  Thanks!..

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the picture in the package of your project and run the code.I hope it will work.
Another process:
Use
`ImageIcon bug = new ImageIcon("java.png");`//In the double quotes write the full path of the image.
instead of `Icon bug = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource( "bug1.png" ) );`
I hope it will also work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Here is the solution... just make a png image (using photoshop) and name it as bug1.png. Now just copy & paste the image in your project's src folder. Thats all.